# Pass a table name to a function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm looking for a way to return one case-insensitive varchar2 from a table given as a parameter.
The database is configured to have as the first column the one I'll look into.
This is what I got to:

```
create or replace function generic_return(nam varchar2, table_n varchar2)
return varchar2
as
    case_insensitive varchar2(300);
    case_ins varchar2(300);
    colu varchar2(30);
    t_nam varchar2(30):=upper(table_n);
    cursor point is execute inmediate select colu from t_nam;
    cursor col is select column_name from cols where table_name=t_nam;
    non_existent_table exception;
begin
    case_ins:=upper(rtrim(ltrim(nam)));
    open col;
    fetch col into colu;
    close col;
    select column_name from cols where table_name=upper(table_n);
    if colu is null then
        raise non_existent_table;
    end if;

    open point;
    loop
    fetch point into case_insensitive;
    exit when point%notfound;
    if upper(case_insensitive)=case_ins then
        return case_insensitive;        
    end if;
    end loop;
    close point;
    return null;
end;    
/
```

The function receives what to look for, and the name of the table to look into, then the first variables are to compare them, t_nam is to use the uppercased version of the second parameter... and from that there's the huge mess: I get the column name from the table in col, from cols, and then I try to make a cursor that goes around checking if what the tuple, going by the same modifications, is the first parameter, or not, if it happens to be, then it should return the unmodified version of the one in the table. Otherwise, it should return "null", which I'll treat differently on each procedure that uses it.
By null I mean nothingness, not the string.

Comment: Your question is broadly unanswerable. You need to edit it to explain what you want if you expect us to  help you. It is always a good idea to post some sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right. That's a pretty huge mess. :-)

For starters, you cannot declare an explicit cursor as an execute immediate statement.

Next, if you want the first column in the table, you need to specify

```
WHERE column_id = 1
```

and then you can just grab it via a `SELECT-INTO`, no need for an explicit cursor.

Then you could try something like:

```
   my_cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
...
   OPEN my_cur FOR 'SELECT ' || first_col || ' FROM ' || t_name;
   LOOP
      FETCH my_cur INTO case_insensitive;
      EXIT WHEN my_cur%NOTFOUND;
      ... logic for match ....
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE my_cur;
```